# Android APK file not working(installing) on KitKat

Tags: android, apk

I am facing a strange issue. I have built an APK using android studio. When I am trying to install the APK manually(placing the APK in sd card) it is not working(Application crashing after installation).

But when I am trying to build the same application from android studio directly using a usb cable it is working as usual. This problem is observed only in android version less than Lollipop.

However, it is getting installed in lollipop and higher version. Someone please let me know any workaround to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

**FYI** The minimum SDK version is 16. So this should not be a problem.

Comment: check the target version minimum and maxinum in gradle file

Comment: Which version of Android studio your using.If you enabled instant run and installing the apk it will crash.

Comment: @preetika I have checked, they are good.

Comment: I think you should use some crash reporting tool like [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) to know where your app is crashing. Check out the docs. It is pretty simple to implement it.

Comment: set `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'` or `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

Comment: @Ram Thanks it worked